# coefficients using cross_val_score

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have used cross_val_score to train the model. Below is the code.

```
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 200)
meanscores = cross_val_score(model, X, r, cv = 10, scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error')
print('\nMean Absolute Error :', meanscores)
```

This will return me the MAE. But how to get the feature_importances_ of the model after above code.

Comment: look at the documentation first. It's very clear. There is a function called ` feature_importances_`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.feature_importances_) is what you are looking for. Hope it helps.